# Data type casting inside a CASE statement

Tags: sql, informix

I am using Informix and have a CASE statement in a query as below:

```
CASE 
 when l.src_country = 'USA' then tl.cat--prodUSA.description
 when l.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type > 0 then tl.fuel_type
 when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat in ("DEF","DEFD") then 4194304
 when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat not in ("DEF","DEFD") then tl.fuel_type
 else 0
 END as product_code
```

In the above statement, `"tl.cat"` is of CHAR type & `"tl.fuel_type"` is of the type INT.

I need to do something like this:

```
CASE 
 when l.src_country = 'USA' then tl.cat--prodUSA.description
 when l.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type > 0 then tl.fuel_type :: CHARACTER
 when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat in ("DEF","DEFD") then 4194304
 when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat not in ("DEF","DEFD") then tl.fuel_type :: CHARACTER
 else 0
 END as product_code
```

But when I try it, I'm getting the below error:

```
Corresponding data types must be compatible in CASE expression or DECODE function. [SQL State=IX000, DB Errorcode=-800]
```

When I try this:

```
CASE
when l.src_country = 'USA' then tl.cat--prodUSA.description
when l.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type > 0 then tl.fuel_type :: CHAR
when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat in ("DEF","DEFD") then '4194304'
when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat not in ("DEF","DEFD") then tl.fuel_type :: CHAR
else '0'
END as product_code
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
Converted value does not fit into the allotted space
```

I need to cast the `tl.fuel_type` as a Character. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: using IBM Informix

Comment: The `ELSE 0` is trying to return an INT.  Using CHAR indicates a length of 1.  You probably need to specify CHAR(7) or something bigger.  How long is `tl.cat`?  It would be easier if you gave us an outline table schema with the types for the `src_country`, `cat`, `fuel_type` columns, and some simple sample data (it looks like 5 rows of data would be sufficient).

Comment: On further scrutiny, it appears you have at least two tables — it is doubly important to provide outline schema information for the columns in each of the tables used in your query.  We shouldn't have to work out how to create a query that illustrates the problem (so we know when we've fixed it).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Based on your advice, i made a change as seene below:

CASE -- different for CAN vs USA query --Field #7
when l.src_country = 'USA' then tl.cat--prodUSA.description
when l.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type > 0 then tl.fuel_type :: CHAR(6)
when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat in ("DEF","DEFD") then '4194304'
when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat not in ("DEF","DEFD") then tl.fuel_type :: CHAR(6)
else '0'
END as product_code

this seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a one table setup like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fuel_info;
CREATE TEMP TABLE fuel_info
(
    src_country    CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    fuel_type      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cat            CHAR(9) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO fuel_info VALUES('USA', 12, 'CAT1');
INSERT INTO fuel_info VALUES('CAN', 10, 'ABC2');
INSERT INTO fuel_info VALUES('CAN',  0, 'DEFD');
INSERT INTO fuel_info VALUES('CAN',  0, 'WXYZ');
INSERT INTO fuel_info VALUES('EUR',  1, 'P3X9');
```

We can adapt the expressions in the question to reproduce the problem.  For example:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN tl.src_country = 'USA' THEN tl.cat--prodUSA.description
    WHEN tl.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type > 0 THEN tl.fuel_type::CHAR
    WHEN tl.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type = 0 AND tl.cat IN ("DEF","DEFD") THEN '4194304'
    WHEN tl.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type = 0 AND tl.cat NOT IN ("DEF","DEFD") THEN tl.fuel_type::CHAR
    ELSE '0'
    END AS product_code
  FROM fuel_info AS tl;
```

This generates the `SQL -1207: Converted value does not fit into the allotted space` error.

You can fix it by specify big enough lengths for the `CHAR` type casts:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN tl.src_country = 'USA' THEN tl.cat--prodUSA.description
    WHEN tl.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type > 0 THEN tl.fuel_type::CHAR(7)
    WHEN tl.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type = 0 AND tl.cat IN ("DEF","DEFD") THEN '4194304'
    WHEN tl.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type = 0 AND tl.cat NOT IN ("DEF","DEFD") THEN tl.fuel_type::CHAR(7)
    ELSE '0'
    END AS product_code
  FROM fuel_info AS tl;
```

This works, producing:

```
CAT1
10
4194304
0
0
```

Comment: Based on your advice, i made a change as seene below: CASE -- different for CAN vs USA query --Field #7 when l.src_country = 'USA' then tl.cat--prodUSA.description when l.src_country = 'CAN' AND tl.fuel_type > 0 then tl.fuel_type :: CHAR(6) when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat in ("DEF","DEFD") then '4194304' when l.src_country = 'CAN' and tl.fuel_type = 0 and tl.cat not in ("DEF","DEFD") then tl.fuel_type :: CHAR(6) else '0' END as product_code this seems to be working.

Comment: Yes — it should.  You chose a length of 6; I used 7 mainly because of the `'4194304'` value.  For the given data, any length from 2 upwards would suffice — the fuel type of 10 needs to be cast to `CHAR(2)` or longer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I will use the query with CHAR(7) and fix the problem.